# LINQ Delegate Lambda Select Statement Bind Child Property

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a delegate for a `Select` statement in LINQ.  Some of the property bindings are to child properties on the object I'm selecting from.

This is the LINQ statement I want to put in my delegate:

```
var list = dataSet.Select(x => new ViewModel()
{
    Name = x.Name,
    ClassType = x.ClassType.Description
};
```

I can get the `Name` no worries with my code, but I do not know how to get the `ClassType.Description`.

Here is my current code:

```
protected Func<Student, ManagerStudentListViewModel> GetSelectStatement()
{
    var studentType = typeof(Student);
    var viewModelType = typeof(ManagerStudentListViewModel);
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");
    var newInstantiationExpression = Expression.New(viewModelType);

    // Name Binding
    var viewModelProperty = viewModelType.GetProperty("Name");
    var studentProperty = studentType.GetProperty("Name");
    var nameMemberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, studentProperty);
    var nameBinding = Expression.Bind(viewModelProperty, nameMemberExpression);

    // ClassType.Description Binding
    // ???

    var bindings = new List<MemberAssignment>() { nameBinding, classTypeBinding  };
    var memberInitExpression = Expression.MemberInit(newInstantiationExpression, bindings);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, ManagerStudentListViewModel>>(memberInitExpression, parameterExpression);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: What's the point in building it up dynamically?  You know exactly what the expression is supposed to look like, you can build that up statically.

Comment: The reason is the "Description" on the child object is language dependent, this approach therefore allows me to put in a call to get the right property given the UICulture.

Comment: You should not be changing your api just because it's in a different language, it should be language neutral.  I would reconsider the design.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, I'll definitely consider what you've said.

Comment: I've thought about it and you're right, a better solution to the design is to deal with language after this part - less complicated, simpler and more concise solution.  But as to the question as asked, you're answer is excellent.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing deeply nested members is no different than accessing any other properties, provided you know the name of the members.  Just create an expression to get the first property, then add the expression to get the second.

```
Expression<Func<Student, ManagerStudentListViewModel>> GetSelectStatement()
{
    var studentType = typeof(Student);
    var viewModelType = typeof(ManagerStudentListViewModel);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");
    var nameValue = Expression.Property(param, "Name");
    var classTypeValue = Expression.Property(
            Expression.Property(param, "ClassType"), // get the class type
            "Description"); // get the description of the class type

    var nameMemberBinding = Expression.Bind(
            viewModelType.GetProperty("Name"),
            nameValue);
    var classTypeMemberBinding = Expression.Bind(
            viewModelType.GetProperty("ClassType"),
            classTypeValue);
    var initializer = Expression.MemberInit(
            Expression.New(viewModelType),
            nameMemberBinding,
            classTypeMemberBinding);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, ManagerStudentListViewModel>>(initializer, param);
}
```